# Are these "parts pickers"? "JLF" and "Little Joey"

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I'm reading company training materials and I don't understand a few terms.  I'm hoping that some of you might be able to decode.  The company receives product and delivers it to work sites.  I believe these are forklifts or ?order pickers?.  An excerpt from the slides:

> "if your branch has a personal man up device like the Little Joey or JLF"...

Can you help me to understand the terms used in that excerpt?  I assume Little Joey is referring to https://bigjoeforklifts.com/pages/products  but I couldn't find "JLF"; perhaps a trade name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company name is "Big Joe", and "Little Joey" is the brand name of their smallest range of products.

JLF is the brand name of a range of products similar to this: https://www.jung-hebetechnik.de/en/product-details/jlf-5/

Answer (score 2):

> I'm reading company training materials and I don't understand a few terms.

So I'm sure that [alephzero's answer is probably correct](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/35373/1633), but you're reading *company training materials.* Acronyms and jargon could mean different things in different fields (sprints and MVP, for example), but I would assume you're reading training material to learn something about your company.

You should find someone in your company you feel comfortable approaching and ask them about this.